# Add Last Child Elements of <div> in some Class

Tags: jquery, html, css, slice

My `<div>` contains 10 images. I want to add a class to the last 3 images. How to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('img').addClass('t2');
    $('#myImageFlow img').slice(12, 16).addClass('t1');
    $("div img:first-child").removeClass('t2');
}
```

I tried this but its not working.

Comment: You have syntax error in your code. You forgot to close your `ready` method. Last line should be `});`

Answer (score 1):

> My  contains 10 images. I want to add last 3 images into some class....

Then why do you use `slice(12, 16)`?! use `slice(-3)`

```
$('#myImageFlow img').slice(-3).addClass('t1');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fWuce/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#test div').slice(-3).addClass('t1');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lt2J4)

Comment: why two times jquery selector ? $($()) is this a typo ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use slice.

```
$(items).slice(-3).addClass('t1');
```

Answer (score 0):

your div have 10 img controls and you are passing 12,16 in slice. Hope it will help you

```
       $('#myImageFlow img').slice(7).addClass('t1');
```

If your are sure that there are only 10 img in that div so no need to supply end parameter in slice that is optional.